# Is this a real problem: warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, warnings

The following code drops the warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary under Windows with MSVC. But im wondering is it a real error in this case or not? I know there is  lots of similar topic here, and i have read lots of similar topics here from this warning. So in this case the returning value is a pointer from "main" function which should be alive until the end of program. If returningLocalPointer would return: "A something; return &something;" then yes it would be a problem, but in this case we return a pointer which exists until "main" ending. Or am i wrong?

```
class A
{
};

A* returningLocalPointer(A* a)
{
    return a;
}

template<typename T>
T const& doWarning(T const& b)
{
    A* c = returningLocalPointer(b);
    return c;            // error if uses call-by-value
}

int main()
{
    A d;
    auto m = doWarning(&d);       //run-time ERROR
}
```

Comment: Using the same identifier `a` in this little snippet for three different things does not help the human readers, is it intentional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a real problem.  Your program's behavior is undefined.  `c` is a different object from the pointer referenced by `b`, and its lifetime ends at the end of `doWarning`.  Those two pointers point to the same `A` object (`d`), but that doesn't mean they're the same object.

---

To illustrate, I'll go more-or-less line-by-line and use diagrams:

```
A d;
auto m = doWarning(&d);
```

This creates an `A` object named `d` and passes an anonymous pointer to that object to `doWarning`.  I'll get to `m` later, but for now the objects in play look like this:

```
               d
┌─────┐       ┌─────┐
│     │       │     │
│  A* ├──────►│  A  │
│     │       │     │
└─────┘       └─────┘
```

---

```
template<typename T>
T const& doWarning(T const& b)
{
```

Here, `T` will be deduced to be `A*`, since that's what got passed to it.
`doWarning` accepts its parameter by reference, so the type of `b` will be `A* const &`.  That is, `b` is a reference to the anonymous pointer to `d` from `main`:

```
 b                                 d
┌───────────┐       ┌─────┐       ┌─────┐
│           │       │     │       │     │
│ A* const& ├──────►│  A* ├──────►│  A  │
│           │       │     │       │     │
└───────────┘       └─────┘       └─────┘
```

---

```
A* c = returningLocalPointer(b);
```

Here you create another pointer, `c`, that points to the same object as `b`.  I won't look at `returningLocalPointer`, since it's more-or-less irrelevant.  This line could be replaced with `A* c = b;` and nothing would change.  Your objects now look like this:

```
 b                                 d
┌───────────┐       ┌─────┐       ┌─────┐
│           │       │     │       │     │
│ A* const& ├──────►│  A* ├──────►│  A  │
│           │       │     │       │     │
└───────────┘       └─────┘       └─────┘
                                     ▲
                     c               │
                    ┌─────┐          │
                    │     │          │
                    │  A* ├──────────┘
                    │     │
                    └─────┘
```

As you can see, `c` is a different object than the object referenced by `b`.

---

```
return c;
```

Since `doWarning` returns an `A* const&` (since `T` is `A*`), this initializes the return value to refer to the local variable `c`:

```
 b                                 d
┌───────────┐       ┌─────┐       ┌─────┐
│           │       │     │       │     │
│ A* const& ├──────►│  A* ├──────►│  A  │
│           │       │     │       │     │
└───────────┘       └─────┘       └─────┘
                                     ▲
return value         c               │
┌───────────┐       ┌─────┐          │
│           │       │     │          │
│ A* const& ├──────►│  A* ├──────────┘
│           │       │     │
└───────────┘       └─────┘
```

---

```
}
```

Now `doWarning` ends, and so its local variable `c` goes out of scope and its lifetime ends.  That leaves `doWarning`'s return value dangling:

```
 b                                 d
┌───────────┐       ┌─────┐       ┌─────┐
│           │       │     │       │     │
│ A* const& ├──────►│  A* ├──────►│  A  │
│           │       │     │       │     │
└───────────┘       └─────┘       └─────┘

return value
┌───────────┐
│           │
│ A* const& ├──────► Nothing here anymore
│           │
└───────────┘
```

---

```
auto m = doWarning(&d);
```

Now we get back to `m`.  `auto` by itself will never deduce a reference type, so the type of `m` is deduced to be `A*`.  That means the program will attempt to copy the pointer referenced by the reference that `doWarning` returned.  The pointer that `doWarning`'s return value referenced no longer exists though.  Trying to copy a nonexistent object is an error, and if a program does so its behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thank you first of all. The missing point was that i wasn't concentrete that when leaving the scope local variable can be destroyed. That means local variable will be invalidated first, then returning. So when returning there will be no local variable available  (worst case).

Answer (score 2):

Let's "instantiate" the function with `T = A*` (as it does when you call it with `doWarning(&d)`):

```cpp
template
A* const& doWarning<A*>(A* const& b)
{
    A* c = returningLocalPointer(&b);
    return c;
}
```

You may be able to see where the problem is. `c` is returned by reference, but it is a local variable that is immediately destroyed, thus `doWarning` will always return a dangling reference.

MSVC seems to use the same warning for pointers-to-locals and references-to-locals, which is why it is talking about addresses when it's really about references. The GCC warning might be more clear:

```cpp
In instantiation of 'const T& doWarning(const T&) [with T = A*]':
warning: reference to local variable 'c' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
    return c;            // error if uses call-by-value
           ^
note: declared here
    A* c = returningLocalPointer(b);
       ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a reference to the local variable `c` so your code has undefined behaviour. You might get "lucky" and `m` will happen to end up being a pointer to `d` but there is no guarantee.

This code would have defined behaviour as it is returning a reference to `d` rather than a reference to `c` though it will still have undefined behaviour (and might therefore still produce a warning) if `doWarning` is called with a temporary value:

```
A* returningLocalPointer(A* a)
{
    return a;
}

template<typename T>
T const& doWarning(T const& b)
{
    A* c = returningLocalPointer(&b);
    return *c;
}

int main()
{
    A d;
    auto& m = doWarning(d);
    // Undefined behaviour
    auto& n = doWarning(A{});
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you, but the address of "c" must be the same with the address of "d". Which exists till the end or?

Comment: No, the value stored in `c` is the same as the address of `d` but the variable `c` itself (which is what you're returning a reference to) is destroyed at the end of the function